# How can a Perfmon "% Processor Time" counter be over 100%?

Tags: windows, cpu-usage, perfmon

The counter, `Process(sqlservr)\% Processor Time`, is hovering around 300% on one of my database servers.  This counter reflects the percent of total time SQL Server spent running on CPU (user mode + privilege mode).  The book, [Sql Server 2008 Internals and Troubleshooting](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470484284), says that anything greater than 80% is a problem.

How is it possible for that counter to be over 100%?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are two counters with the same name:

`Process\% Processor Time`: The **sum** of processor time on **each processor**

`Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time`: The total for all processors

Your question indicates you're using the first counter, which means that its maximum value is 100% * (no of CPUs).

So if you have 4 CPUs, then the total maximum is 400%, and 80% is actually (400 * 0.8 =) 320% (and for 8 CPUs it's 640%, etc etc)

Comment: Yep! That's it. I have 8 CPUs. So my sqlservr total CPU usage is actually about 37%.  And that means everything is normal.  Thanks, @Farseeker!

Comment: Any time. I had similar queries when I first started using perfmon on multiple-cpu systems.

Comment: Does the number of CPUs include hyperthreading? For example, if my computer is quad core and I have hyperthreading, should I factor in 4 procs or 8?

Comment: Is there a way to find the processor usage of a single process with a value between 0 and 100% (aka: it shows you the spread load over all CPUs)? I'd prefer not to do the dividing myself

Answer (score 0):

This value is calculated over the base line of
(No of Logical CPUS * 100),  So this is going to be a calculated over a baselin of more than 100.